# I need to display the hex value of a file field value in display file in a rpgle program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I need to read a file using RPGLE and then display the Hexadecimal value of some of the fields of the file in a display file.

Can someone tell me how to get the hex value of a field in a rpgle program and display it in a display file.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

RPG IV doesn't have any built in HEX() function...

However, [SQL does](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-hex).

```
dcl-s myCharString varchar(100);
dcl-s myHexString varchar(200);

exec sql
  values hex(:myCharString) into :myHexString;
```

Optionally, you can use the MI [Convert Hex to Character (CVTHC)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzatk/CVTHC.htm)* instruction using a prototype like so...

```
dcl-pr CharToHex ExtProc('cvthc');
   hexResult    Char(65534)  Options(*VarSize);
   charInput    Char(32767)  Options(*VarSize);
   charNibbles  Int(10)  Value;
End-Pr;

dcl-s myCharString varchar(100);
dcl-s myHexString varchar(200);

CharToHex ( myHexString : myCharString : %len(myCharString) * 2 );
```

*Note the MI name(s) are counter-intuitive, the reverse operation is
***Convert Character to Hex (CVTCH).***

Here's a good article by Jon Paris, [Practicing Safe Hex in RPG](https://www.itjungle.com/2020/03/02/guru-practicing-safe-hex-in-rpg/),  about the MI functions.